# Python's sqlite3.register_converter() does not convert double to Decimal

Tags: python, sqlite

In sqlite3 there is this table:

```
create table t(d double)
```

In python, the code is:

```
sqlite3.register_converter('double', Decimal)
...
for d, in connection.execute('select d from t limit 1'):
    print type(d)
```

The printed result is: `<type 'float'>`
Any idea why?

Comment: sqlite AFAIK isn't strong-typed, maybe that's why. Wait for an answer from someone who really knows that, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

connect to the database using the optional argument:

```
detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
```

ie:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
```

then continue as you have. It should work.

see:

http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/627047